# Why is onChange getting fired repeatedly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to upload images.

```html
<input type="file" name="file_<?php echo $i?>" style="display: none;" id="file_<?php echo $i?>" onchange="do_upload_item_image(<?php echo $i?>,true);"/>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('file_<?php echo $i?>').click();"/>
    <img title="Enviar imagem" src="<?php echo item_image(null, 120)?>" id="img_<?php echo $i?>" data-newid="0"/>
</a>
```

So that, basically, when a user clicks the image it "clicks" the `input file` so that the user can select a file and upload it. The `do_upload_item_image` calls `ajaxFileUpload` to handle the upload assynchronously and displays the uploaded image.

It was all working all and good, until I tested it today and realized that each file is getting uploaded 21 TIMES! I placed an `alert` on the `do_upload_item_image` and it is getting called 21 TIMES.

Any ideas?

Comment: when on change happens remove event listener in do_upload_item_image

Comment: What if the user wants to upload a new file?

Comment: Did you try creating on change event listener with JS on page load?

document.getElementById("file").onchange = function() { your stuff};

Comment: No I didn't, I can try that. But I really wanted to understand why is it happening. (btw: I have already worked around the problem with a `uploadInProgress` flag until I can find the best and final solution)